# Run Robocopy in "Report Only" Mode

Tags: robocopy

I have a fairly simple robocopy command here that I want to run that will upload files to an Azure storage account. The problem I have is I'm looking at approxiately 70,000 files but a lot of these already exist in the storage account.

What I want to do is run the command in a "Log Only" or "whatif" mode so I can see how many files will be copied and how many will be skipped. This command gives that detail but will perform the copy. Is there a switch I can add that will simply provide the log and **NOT** copy the files?

```
S:\inbound\ \\<storageaccount>\<filesharename>\inbound\ /r:3 /w:3 /e /xo /xx /LOG:Robocopy_20200313_Manual.txt
```

Comment: `robocopy /?` from a command prompt will tell you what it can and can't do and what switches it supports.

Comment: Yes it does (although it won't tell me what I can't do). I've also checked the reference doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy but couldn't find what I need. There is a `/nocopy` option but that looks more like an attribute switch. I was hoping someone has found a switch or combination of switches that I've missed or haven't been able to figure out.

Comment: It can't do anything it doesn't tell you it can. For instance, if it doesn't say */co Makes your morning coffee*, then it doesn't have a way to make the coffee for you in the morning.  :-) If you don't see a switch that says *test mode* or *trial mode* or anything like that, then it doesn't have a switch that supports that functionality.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you may try the switch /L which means List Only but Will Not Copy any files or Change any attributes.